# Blazor WebAssembly Oidc Authentication works fine locally, but on Azure Static Web Apps has 404 on authentication/login-callback

Tags: blazor-webassembly, .net-5

I have a Blazor .Net5 WebAssembly that uses Auth0 OIDC authentication.  I setup the authentication following these instructions: https://auth0.com/blog/securing-blazor-webassembly-apps/

Following those instructions I was able to develop my app locally and get it working with Auth0 authentication.  However, when I deploy the app using Azure Static Web Apps the authentication is no longer functional.  Looking in the developer tools of Chrome I can see that it successfully (302) calls my authorization endpoint:

```
https://login.mysite.com/authorize?clientid=*****...  (302)
```

The next url is the callback to my site, which fails with a 404:

```
https://myapp.mysite.com/authentication/login-callback?code=***... (404)
```

I do have the following in my index.html:

```
<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>
```

Any idea of what I can do to fix this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added a routes.json file to wwwroot with the following to fix the issue.

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "route": "/*",
      "serve": "/index.html",
      "statusCode": 200
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Works great thanks! On my side I had to add a route to my api to make sure it's not served by Blazor.  { "route": "/api/*" }

Comment: Thanks for this, how did you figure that out?!

Comment: Thanks, it solved my issue as well for a Blazor WASM deployed in a Azure Static App and integrated with Azure B2C.